# RStudio Shiny: The confliction between an action button and a submit button

Tags: r, shiny

In my R Shiny app, I have an action and a submit button.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  X = reactive(data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rpois(10,10),z=runif(10)))
  Y = eventReactive(input$flush, {
    X()[,sample(1:3)]
  },ignoreNULL=FALSE)

  output$distPlot <- renderTable({
    Y()    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("flush","flush order"),
  submitButton("update"),
  tableOutput("distPlot") 
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I want:
The order of variables randomly changing when I click the action button.

What happens:
I have to click action button first and subsequently click the submit button to get this to execute.

Question:
How can I get the desired behavior while keeping that submit button.

There are many tabs with more submit buttons in my app. So it's most desirable that we could just add an action button without affecting the rest of the contents.

Comment: Its best if you change your submit button to `actionbutton`. If you like the style of the `submitbutton` then you can easily style it yourself

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed but in a later version of shiny having `submitbutton`s on different tabs caused a lot of trouble. One tab would wait on any `submitbutton` to update it's contents. Even if the `submitbutton` was located in another tab.